# Why is the spectrometer so big in KATRIN experiment?

Tags: magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, electrons, spectroscopy, neutrinos

I've been studying KATRIN experiment for a popularizing science project and I was wondering, **why is the spectrometer so big ?** I mean the thing is so huge that they had to carry it over 8000km on the sea, it is 24meters long and had a diameter of 10m. But in all the publications related I didn't find any hint, only that the precision of the filter is given by:
$$\frac{\Delta E}{E} = \frac{B_{\text{min}}}{B_{\text{max}}}$$
which involves only magnitude of magnetic field. They also want the magnetic field to vary adiabatically which involves:
$$\nabla B/ B << 1$$
That can explain the length, but why this **ovoid shape** ?
I'm not an expert of this field if someone can give a clear and precise answer I'll be very grateful !

Thank you,

[image: The spectrometer in a street]

Comment: You write: "they also want the magnetic field to vary adiabatically" It's not clear what you mean by that. In my answer I linked to the [measurement principle](https://www.katrin.kit.edu/79.php) webpage. There it is described that the magnetic field that the electrons must negotiate is designed to have decreasing flux per unit of area from the point of entry to halfway along the length of the chamber. The effect of that on the motion of the electrons: "[...] the momentum transforms adiabatically" From halfway along the chamber to the point of exit the flux per unit of area increases again.

Comment: @Cleonis what I mean is they want to keep $\mu = E_T/B$ as a constant, it involves that the magnetic field has to vary slowly in space. I used the terminology from the articles but I agree it's not very clear as I wrote it without the context ...

Comment: In retrospect I suppose you were too eager to provide details. In my opinion providing links to context is best. That said: I certainly recommend that next to providing links you alway describe the context yourself; it shows effort, and the way you describe it gives the reader a way to assess your level of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assumming you obtained your information from the page on the katrin.kit.edu website where the [measurement principle](https://www.katrin.kit.edu/79.php) of a MAC-E-filter is discussed

The objective is to obtain the highest resolution that current technology can obtain.

The electrons entering the main filter have already undergone multiple stages of pre-filtering, second to last in a smaller (but still very large) MAC-E-filter, so the electrons entering the main filter already have an energy very close to each other.

I don't see *explicit* mention anywhere of why the main chamber is so large.

I assume that if the "main" chamber would be of similar size to the chamber of the pre-filter the "main" chamber wouldn't add all that much.

I assume that the larger the chamber of the main filter the higher the resolution of the cut-off that the setup is designed to obtain.

From the 2004 [KATRIN design report](https://inspirehep.net/files/d0b873303dc46c7fc8fcbf1f01fd909d):
Section 2.1.1 (page 36) describes that it is also possible to build the setup in such a way that it also support a time-of-flight mode.

"By measuring the time-of-flight of the electrons those of interest can be distinguished fromthe high energy electrons and the MAC-E-Filter transforms from an energy high-passfilter into an energy band-pass filter of the same energy resolution and nearly the sameluminosity as the MAC-E-Filter without time-of-flight measurement"

When set up to operate in time-of-flight mode the separation is based on duration of the flight. The bigger the chamber, the longer the total duration of the flight, the more time available for separation.

As you know, the researchers are interested only in the electrons that carry away so much energy from the decay event that the neutrino formed in that event received only the energy that is the minimum it needs to be formed at all. All electrons that carry away less than that maximum need to be washed away. The electrons that even make it to the main chamber will have energies very, very close to each other. That of course makes separation very, very hard to obtain.